# taking specific info out of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Below is the code I have written. What I'm trying to do is say enter 3 players names and the number of goals they have scored. Then the application should output the players name with the most goals and his number of goals. Also the application should output the lowest number of goals scored and the average goals scored. I can get the max goals scored but I cant figure out how to link the players name to goals scored. Also when I try and get the lowest goals scored I keep getting a value of 0. Thanks for the help.

```
 {
        string []player = new string[20];
        double [] goalsScored = new double[20];
        int numberOfPlayers;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of players:");
        numberOfPlayers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a players name:");
            player[i]= Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Goals scored so far this season");
            goalsScored [i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        double max = goalsScored.Max();         
        double sum = goalsScored.Sum();
        double average = sum / numberOfPlayers;

        Console.WriteLine("Top player is: {0} with {1} goals", player, max);

        Console.WriteLine("The average goals scored was:{0}",average);

        double min = goalsScored.Min();

        Console.WriteLine("The lowest goals scored was: {0}", min);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Firstly, I would try to have *one* collection with the information, e.g. `List<Player>` where `Player` has a name and a score. Using a `List<>` instead of an array will make various things simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Linq solution :)

```
var players = player.Zip(goalsScored, (n,g) => new { Name = n, Goals = g });
var topGoalscorer = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Goals).First();
var misser = players.OrderBy(p => p.Goals).First();

topGoalscorer.Goals // max goals
topGoalscorer.Name  // player name
```

Using goals value:

```
string playerName = player[Array.IndexOf(goalsScored, min)];
```

Alternative solution:

```
int maxScoredGoals = -1;
string topGoalscorer = "";

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayes; i++)
{
   if (goalsScored[i] <= maxScoredGoals)
       continue;

    maxScoredGoals = goalsScored[i];
    topGoalsocrer = player[i];
}
```

---

Suggestions: use single data structure to hold related data, i.e. player name and scored goals

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Goals { get; set; }
}
```

Also use generic collection instead of arrays:

```
List<Player> players = new List<Player>();
```

Filling collection:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
{
    var player = new Player();
    player.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    player.Goals = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    players.Add(player);
}
```

Getting top goalscorer:

```
var topGoalscorer = players.OrderByDescending(p => p.Goals).First().Name;
```

Or with MoreLINQ:

```
var topGoalscorer = players.MaxBy(p => p.Goals).Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the number of players first, then create your arrays using that number.

For example:

```
string[] player = new string[numberOfPlayers];
```

This may explain why you're always getting zero as the minimum score. If your array contains empty spots (if you entered less than 20 players/scores).

To "link" the player's name with his goals scored, you should really use a `Player` class so you can just have a single array of `Player` objects and use it for both scores and names. Then you'd end up with something like:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Top player is: {0} with {1} goals", topPlayer.name, topPlayer.score);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this easily using arrays. You could use a Dictionary, which would allow you to look up a player's name and get the goals out. Indeed this sort of pairing of values is kind of what dictionaries are for:

```
//declare a dictionary string, int. The "string" is the name which we look up to get the 
//second data point of "int", which will be the number of goals
Dictionary<string, int> playerGoals = new Dictionary<string, int>();

//add a couple of players, and their goal tally
playerGoals.Add("Gianfranco Zola", 44);
playerGoals.Add("Wayne Rooney", 77);

//use the string name to retrieve the int value
int rooneyGoals = playerGoals["Wayne Rooney"];
//rooneyGoals is now 77
```

Quicky whipped through your original code - something like this should work:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> playerGoals = new Dictionarty<string, int>()'
    int numberOfPlayers;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of players:");
    numberOfPlayers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPlayers; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a players name:");
        string playerName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Goals scored so far this season");
        int goalsScored = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        playerGoals.Add(playerName, goalsScored);
    }

    double max = playerGoals.Values.Max();        
    double sum = playerGoals.Values.Sum();
    double average = sum / numberOfPlayers;

    Console.WriteLine("Top player is: {0} with {1} goals", player, max);

    Console.WriteLine("The average goals scored was:{0}",average);

    double min = playerGoals.Values.Min(); 

    Console.WriteLine("The lowest goals scored was: {0}", min);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indirect sorting using [`Array.Sort(goalsScored, players);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h22cx4f.aspx) to keep a second array in sync while sorting an array. Other issues are addressed in the comments in the following code.

```
var numberOfPlayers = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

// Allocate the arrays with the correct size; in your code numberOfPlayers
// larger than 20 will cause trouble.
var players = new String[numberOfPlayers];

var goalsScored = new Double[numberOfPlayers];

// Fill the arrays as in your code.

// This will sort the goalsScored array and simultaneously
// bring the players array into the same order; that is called
// indirect sorting.  
Array.Sort(goalsScored, players);

// The maximum number of goals scored and the associated player
// are now in the last array position.
var topPlayer = players.Last();

var maxNumberGoals = goalsScored.Last();

// You always got 0 because you always allocated arrays of size
// 20 and if you have less than 20 players all the superfluous
// entries in the array just have their default value of 0 making
// the minimum in the array 0. 
var minNumberGoals = goalsScored.First();

var totalNumberGoals = goalsScored.Sum();

var averageNumberGoals = goalsScored.Average();
```

Unfortunately there is only out of the box support for this with arrays while it might be better to use lists and just add new players and scores until the users says that there are no more players to be entered instead of forcing the user to enter the number of players in advance.

Other answer suggest to use a more object oriented design and combine players and scored goals into a class or at least use a dictionary and I really suggest the same but I won't bother duplicating answers already here.